# Is is possible to restore SQL Server 2014 Express backup data in mongodb and how to do it?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, database

My friend got a new project to work. He said the data is stored in SQL Server 2014 Express and planning to build new front-end based on it. I'm thinking of changing the database to like Mongodb. I know it is no sql database. Is it possible to restore whole data from SQL Server 2014 to Mongodb?

Comment: I would be shocked, shocked if there were possible.  Restore the database into SQL Server and export the data to MongoDB.  SQL Server Express is free, so you won't even need paid software to do this.

Comment: Does this work for you?

Comment: Hello @DanGreen-Leipciger . Thank you for your response. I'm waiting for my friend reply. Soon, will let you know the status. I hope this fix works.